# Programmatic access to USSD from the Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, ussd

I have a Windows 10 Desktop application that needs USSD access, and can get operator permission to use it. 
However, I can’t use AT commands (COM ports are not exposed), and USSD is not offered by the Windows Desktop Mobile Broadband APIs.
I thought of using the Windows Runtime USSD module, but this would require a side-loaded Windows Runtime app to run alongside the Desktop app.  The Windows Runtime App could be closed by the system at any time, and the user starts the dialogue from the Windows Desktop App, so won’t re-start the Runtime App.

Is there any better way of accessing USSD programmatically on the Windows 10 Desktop?

Comment: UssdSession [has the dualapipartition attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.networkoperators.ussdsession.aspx), which means you can use it directly from a desktop app.

Comment: @RaymondChen, please could you write it as an answer and I will mark the question solved. Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question, then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Raymond. The search for this [dualapipartition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute.aspx) attribute brought me to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/09/24/winrt-for-desktop-apps.aspx. This link describes how to tweak the Visual Studio project to get access to several WinRT APIs.